# Get user local time

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g, timezone

The date/time data in the database is stored as Oracle Time Stamp with Time Zone (02-FEB-2013 13:25:00 US/PACIFIC).
When I read the data I need to determine the difference between this time and user's current local time. Using above, I can get user's local time offset:

```
OracleTimeStampTZ dtzLastActivity = new OracleTimeStampTZ(dr["LAST_ACTIVITY_TZ"].ToString());
TimeSpan tsOffset = dtzLastActivity.GetTimeZoneOffset();
```

Can I get the local time, maybe using TimeZoneInfo, knowing only the offset, so I can then subtract the time in database from local time to get the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`US/Pacific` is an [IANA/Olson](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) time zone identifier - not a Windows time zone id.  So you can't use the `TimeZoneInfo` classes for it.

Instead, use a TZDB implementation, such as [NodaTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/).  It has full awareness of these types of time zones, and can do the type of calculation you are looking for.

BTW - `US/Pacific` as actually an alias for `America/Los_Angeles`.  You can find a list of these time zones [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I overlooked that you are using `OracleTimeStampTZ`.  This [appears](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleTimeStampTZStructure.htm) to already implement the TZDB, so you should be able to use it directly.  Try the following:

```
var span = DateTime.UtcNow - dtzLastActivity.ToUniversalTime().Value;
```

Comment: @Aristos I think I did not convey what I needed correctly. I need the time difference between what is in the database and, not user's local time but the local time of the same offset. So, if the column contains date/time for Pacific, ragardless of where the user viewing the data is, I need to get the Pacific's local time to display the difference.